# Declare vector of SystemC type sc_fix

Tags: c++, vector, systemc

I am trying to make a `std::vector` of type `sc_fix` .  I know that I can make `std::vector<sc_fixed<WL,IWL, ...>> name;` . However I would like to use the non-template version `sc_fixed`. However I am not sure how to instantiate this vector and set the word and integer bit lengths as I can not declare it the same was as the templated version.

I have tried making an array to fill in a memory space of the same  type, but this gives me an error as well.

```
sc_fix* img_num (32, 15, SC_RND_ZERO, SC_SAT_ZERO);
img_num[0] = 12.12;
img_num[1] = 12.12;
img_num[2] = 12.12;
img_num[3] = 12.12;
std::vector<sc_fix> img (img_num, img_num+sizeof(img_num) / sizeof(img_num[0]));
```

This gives me the error

```
Main_Test.cpp: In function ‘int sc_main(int, char**)’:
Main_Test.cpp:24: error: initializer expression list treated as compound expression
Main_Test.cpp:24: error: cannot convert ‘sc_dt::sc_o_mode’ to ‘sc_dt::sc_fix*’ in initialization
make: *** [Main_Test] Error 1
```

What is causing this error and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to remove the `*` after `sc_fix` do declare a variable of type `sc_fix`, not pointer-to `sc_fix*`, and call it's constructor:

```
sc_fix img_num (32, 15, SC_RND_ZERO, SC_SAT_ZERO);
```

The compiler tried to initialize a pointer and complained about the too many initializes provided.

But I think what you want to do is allocate vector with 4 numbers:

```
std::vector<sc_fix> img_num (4, sc_fix(32, 15, SC_RND_ZERO, SC_SAT_ZERO));
img_num[0] = 12.12;
img_num[1] = 12.12;
img_num[2] = 12.12;
img_num[3] = 12.12;
```